# Why is a simple "goto $argv[1];" not working?

Tags: php

Im trying to use a $argv content together with a goto command.
A simple

```
goto $argv[1];
```

gives me back:

> syntax error, unexpected '$argv' (T_VARIABLE), expecting identifier
>   (T_STRING)

no idea what to do...

Comment: Using `goto` is very bad practice! Avoid it at all costs!

Comment: Its not working because its a variable/string, not an identifier.

Comment: See https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php, specfically https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php#106323

Comment: Well I see the problem. I'll change to a if else construct...